# What does "having excellent Likelihoods" mean ? (MCMC code)

Tags: covariance, markov-chain-montecarlo, likelihood, covariance-matrix, chi-squared-distribution

I asked an astrophysicist about MontePython code (MCMC code). **He told me that its team had excellent Likelihoods about a cosmological survey.**

What does "having excellent Likelihoods" mean ?

I know the Likelihood can be computed by factorize all PDF (Probability Density Function) for given experimental or simulated data.

I know also that the Likelihood is related to the $\chi^2$ by : $\ln \mathcal L = -\dfrac{1}{2}\,\chi^2$.

But there also the relation : $\chi^2 = (x-\bar x)^{T}\text{Cov}^{-1}(x-\bar x)$

**Maybe saying that we have "excellent Likelihoods" means that we have a good data Covariance matrix "$\text{Cov}$"** ? then it would imply that with this covariance matrix "$\text{Cov}$", the $\chi^2$ associated is very minimal, wouldn't it ?

(this matrix is related to $\sigma_i$ and whose inverse is the Fisher matrix (I am not sure of this)), is it right ?

Any explanation is welcome.

Comment: The $\chi^2_n$ relation is approximate (or asymptotic) and only working in relation with model comparison. A "good" likelihood value could be taken a value near its maximum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask them what they meant, as it means nothing. For some reason they seem to have liked the results, but “excellent” does not have any specific statistical meaning beyond the plain English meaning.